# Select DISTINCT According to Order of Another Column in Hive

Tags: hive

In Hive I have a table which looks like this:

```
  id | tier
  ---------
   1 | silver
   2 | silver
   3 | gold
   4 | platinum
   1 | gold
   3 | platinum
```

Tier is ordered ascending like silver, gold, platinum. I want to do a SELECT DISTINCT from the table such that, if an id appears more than once, the row with the highest tier is the one that's selected.

So the final table should look like this

```
  id | tier
  ---------
   2 | silver
   4 | platinum
   1 | gold
   3 | platinum
```

How can I write such a query? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT id , tier ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tier ORDER BY id desc) from tbalename  as rno) 
SELECT id , tier from CTE where rno=1;
```

Link ROW_NUMBER()
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Link CTE
https://blogs.oracle.com/taylor22/entry/hive_0_11_may_15